# Alternate elements of different columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, alternate

I have 2 dataframes columns like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['CINO','KONO','ROLO','MANE','TUTU']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':['NION','PONO','RZCO','MPPE','TQAS']})
```

My idea is to combine the dataframes in such a way that the output looks like this:

```
        C
CC1  CINO   <---- belongs to A
CC1  NION  <---- belongs to B
CC2  KONO   <---- belongs to A    
CC2  PONO  <---- belongs to B
CC3  ROLO   <---- belongs to A
CC3  RZCO  <---- belongs to B
CC4  MANE   <---- belongs to A
CC4  MPPE  <---- belongs to B
CC5  TUTU   <---- belongs to A
CC5  TQAS  <---- belongs to B
```

As you can see the items of column `B` are placed between the rows of column `A`.
Notice how the rows are named in such a way that every pair of rows has the same name.

Can you suggest me a smart way to achieve this goal using some built in Pandas function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pd.concat(
    [df1, df2], axis=1
).stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).to_frame('C').rename(index='CC{}'.format)

        C
CC0  CINO
CC0  NION
CC1  KONO
CC1  PONO
CC2  ROLO
CC2  RZCO
CC3  MANE
CC3  MPPE
CC4  TUTU
CC4  TQAS
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.rename(columns={'A':'C'}),
                df2.rename(columns={'B':'C'})], keys=[1,2])
       .sort_index(level=[1,0])
       .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df.index = 'CC' + df.index.astype(str)
print (df)
        C
CC0  CINO
CC0  NION
CC1  KONO
CC1  PONO
CC2  ROLO
CC2  RZCO
CC3  MANE
CC3  MPPE
CC4  TUTU
CC4  TQAS
```