# Combine two columns in pandas dataframe but in specific order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

For example, I have a dataframe where two of the columns are "Zeroes" and "Ones" that contain only zeroes and ones, respectively. If I combine them into one column I get first all the zeroes, then all the ones.

I want to combine them in a way that I get each element from both columns, not all elements from the first column and all elements from the second column. So I don't want the result to be [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], I need it to be [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1].

I process 100K+ rows of data. What is the fastest or optimal way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some code showing what you have already tried?

Comment: Well, it isn't hard to do it iteratively, loop through the columns, append the element from the first column, then append element from the second column but I guess there is a faster, more "pandas" way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ "zeroes" : [0, 0, 0], "ones":  [1, 1, 1], "some_other" : list("abc")})
res = df[["zeroes", "ones"]].to_numpy().ravel(order="C")
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0 1 0 1 0 1]
```

**Micro-Benchmarks**

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
df = pd.DataFrame({ "zeroes" : [0] * 10_000, "ones":  [1] * 10_000})
%timeit df[["zeroes", "ones"]].to_numpy().ravel(order="C").tolist()
672 µs ± 8.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit [v for vs in zip(df["zeroes"], df["ones"]) for v in vs]
2.57 ms ± 54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(zip(df["zeroes"], df["ones"]))) 
2.11 ms ± 73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: good solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) like below as alternative:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df[["zeroes", "ones"]].to_numpy().flatten()
```

Benchmark *(runnig on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/))*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "zeroes" : [0] * 10_000_000, "ones":  [1] * 10_000_000})

%timeit df[["zeroes", "ones"]].to_numpy().flatten().tolist()
1 loop, best of 5: 320 ms per loop

%timeit df[["zeroes", "ones"]].to_numpy().ravel(order="C").tolist()
1 loop, best of 5: 322 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most optimal solution but it should solve your case.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0 for x in range(10)], [1 for x in range(10)]]).T
l = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(df[0], df[1])]
l = [x for y in l for x in y]
l
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: [Alternate elements of different columns using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808772/alternate-elements-of-different-columns-using-pandas)

```
pd.concat(
    [df1, df2], axis=1
).stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).to_frame('C').rename(index='CC{}'.format)
```